# Rails 4.2 relationship cannot be accessed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I set up models `Region` and `Event` with the following subclass and schema:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: :region, foreign_key: :region_id
end

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 1) do
  create_table "region", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer :region_id, index: true
  end
  create_table "event", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.belongs_to :region, index: true
  end
end
```

Based on that alone, I'm expecting to be able to do the following, which returns me nothing:

```
region = Region.all.first
events = region.events # returns nil, why?
```

I've been looking around for an hour, but there are only so many things I know to look...  Basically `Region` must have 2 ids `id` and `region_id`, and I'm using `region_id` as the foreign key, which I've created on table `event`.  Then I set the associations in the `ActiveRecord::Base` subclass.  Is there anything I missed?  The generated `has_many` association method returns `nil` every time. :(

Note: I can see the `region_id` property in the `Event` objects.  I'm not sure what else I need to say to Rails so that it knows what to do.

Comment: `B` beongs_to `A`.. `B` has _one-to-one_ relationship with `A`. you should call `b.a`, not `b.as`. On the other side `A` has_may `B`, so `A` has _one_to_many_ relationship with `B`, so you should call `a.bs`.

Comment: sorry, let me edit my question, i confused myself trying to be generic :D

Comment: why is `region_id` is in the `regions` table, it should be in the events table

Comment: `region_id` gets created from `t.belongs_to :region, index: true`.  I have an extra `region_id` in the `regions` table so that `events` use that (and not the default `id` attribute) as the foreign key association.

Comment: ok seems you have it on both tables, so i guess it doesn't matter, an easy way to debug this is to see the sql, try `puts region.events.to_sql`

Comment: `SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "events"."region_id" = 1` returns `nil`, that's consistent.  The query I want it to do though is without the `events` in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the `:primary_key` column to associate to on the `Region` model.

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events, primary_key: :region_id
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region, foreign_key: :region_id, primary_key: :region_id
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was missing, baby!